# Remove rows that have a specific value in any column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fav-animal-sound' : ['meow', 'woof','quack', 'moo', '?'],
                     'fav-word' : ['foo', 'bar','?', 'ho', 'hum'],
                     'fav-celeb' : ['cher', 'britney','bono', '?', 'big_bird']})
```

In this dataset, `'?'` is a common placeholder in several columns for unknown values. I want to remove these values.

This works with one column at a time:

```
valid_entries = df.loc[:, "fav-celeb"] != '?'
```

But this does not work:

```
valid_entries = df.loc[:, "fav-celeb", "fav-word", "fav-animal-sound"] != '?'
```

I would like to apply the `valid_entries` flag to each row which does not have a '?' in any of the selected columns, then remove them with something like:

```
df = df.loc[valid_entries]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform element wise comparison on the whole DataFrame. This is how you'd do it:

```
df[(df != '?').all(1)]

  fav-animal-sound fav-word fav-celeb
0             meow      foo      cher
1             woof      bar   britney
```